# Capture ctr-z(undo) and ctr-y(redo) within GWT application

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, jakarta-ee, jsni

I have been writing a web application baased on GWT 2.3  and along with it I have written my own undo and redo functions. When the user presses ctr-z or ctr-y the undoes or redoes the last changes. Is their a way to effectively detect the ctr-z and ctr-y keypress events that occur anywhere on the page and cause them to run my own functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a [`NativePreviewHandler`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/Event.NativePreviewHandler.html):

```
Event.addNativePreviewHandler(new NativePreviewHandler() {
  @Override
  public void onPreviewNativeEvent(NativePreviewEvent event) {
    if (event.getTypeInt() == Event.ONKEYDOWN) {
      NativeEvent ne = event.getNativeEvent();

      if (ne.getCtrlKey() && ne.getKeyCode() == 'Z') {
        event.cancel();
        // Handle undo
      } else if (ne.getCtrlKey() && ne.getKeyCode() == 'Y') {
        event.cancel();
        // Handle redo
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it did not work for me
To debug I changed your code to log the keys pressed. Event.addNativePreviewHandler(new NativePreviewHandler()
      {
         @Override
         public void onPreviewNativeEvent(NativePreviewEvent event)
         {
            if (event.getTypeInt() == Event.ONKEYDOWN)
            {
               NativeEvent ne = event.getNativeEvent();

               GWT.log(ne.getCtrlKey() ? " CTRL" : "" + ne.getKeyCode());
            }
         }
      });

Comment: and the result was always the same regardless of the selected key with "ctr"
logged result when i click ctr+y or ctr+z.. was: CTRL 17

Note I used Firefox to test

Comment: My apologies, you need to use the capital characters instead of the lower case I originally included in my sample. I've updated the answer. The CRTL 17 you see is for the control key - 17 is the ASCII code for the control key - if you hold control and press another key you will see a different character code.